# Bundler locks in docker + can't install gems (Solved- docker CMD vs ENTRYPOINT)

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, bundler

Update: I've narrowed the [or a?] problem down to the line `- groupy-gemcache:/usr/local/bundle` in my `services: app: volumes` dictionary. If I remove it, the container runs fine [i think] but presumably i lose my local gem cacheing.

tldr: After running docker-compose build, things seem ok, but I cannot run **any** `gem` or `bundle` inside my running docker container if I add something to my gemfile. for example, after `docker-compose build && docker-compose run app bash`:

```
root@2ea58aff612e:/src# bundle check
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
root@2ea58aff612e:/src# echo 'gem "hello-world"' >> Gemfile
root@2ea58aff612e:/src# bundle
Could not find gem 'hello-world' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
root@2ea58aff612e:/src# bundle install
Could not find gem 'hello-world' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
root@2ea58aff612e:/src# gem
Could not find gem 'hello-world' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
root@2ea58aff612e:/src# gem env
Could not find gem 'hello-world' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I'm still pretty novice with docker, but i've been trying to configure a perfect dockerfile that can build, cache gems and update while still committing its Gemfile.lock to git [maybe this isn't actually perfect and I'm open to suggestions there]. In my use case, I'm using a docker compose file with images for a rails app and sidekiq worker as well as postgres and redis images- very simliar to the setups described [here](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-ruby-on-rails-application) and [here](https://runnable.com/docker/rails/dockerize-your-ruby-on-rails-application).

My Dockerfile [some things commented out that I cobbled from the tutorials above:

```
    FROM ruby:2.3
    ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]
    ARG bundle_path
    # throw errors if Gemfile has been modified since Gemfile.lock
    # RUN bundle config --global frozen 1
    ENV INSTALL_PATH /src
    RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
    WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH



    # Install dependencies:
    # - build-essential: To ensure certain gems can be compiled
    # - nodejs: Compile assets
    # - npm: Install node modules
    # - libpq-dev: Communicate with postgres through the postgres gem
    # - postgresql-client-9.4: In case you want to talk directly to postgres
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y build-essential nodejs npm libpq-dev postgresql-client-9.4 --fix-missing --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

    COPY app/Gemfile app/Gemfile.lock ./

    # Bundle and then save the updated Gemfile.lock in our volume since it will be clobbered in the next step
    RUN echo $bundle_path && bundle install --path=$bundle_path && \
    cp Gemfile.lock $bundle_path

    # ./app contains the rails app on host
    COPY app .

    # Unclobber the updated gemfile.lock
    RUN mv $bundle_path/Gemfile.lock ./

    CMD ["./script/start.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  groupy-redis:
  groupy-postgres:
  groupy-gemcache:

services:
  app:
    build: 
      args:
        bundle_path: /usr/local/bundle
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: "./script/start.sh"
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./app:/src
      - groupy-gemcache:/usr/local/bundle
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    env_file:
      - .docker.env
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, I figured it out. The problem was coming from my ENTRYPOINT dockerfile command, as explained at the end of [this article on CMD vs ENTRYPOINT](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd).

I believe the result of `ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]` with `CMD ["./script/start.sh"]` OR `docker-compose run app bash` was to run a command like `bundle exec 'bash'`. I confirmed this by removing the entrypoint from the dockerfile, entering the shell as above and manually running `bundle exec 'bash'` and sure enough i landed in a subshell where I couldn't run any bundle or gem commands- had to `exit` twice to leave.

Comment: very happy you posted this I was getting the same error message and switching to CMD from ENTRYPOINT made `docker-compose run web bundle install` work